# In Angular 2, what is right way to place the components, i can see last page as well & the next component i have loaded,?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-components

Here it's my first component placed

[image]

2nd Img is html of menu component

[image]

Now suppose I make a route on a link & I call 3rd image page, I can see 1st page as well & 2nd components comes over it

[image]

Comment: Paste the code here instead of image.

Answer (score 0):

You can just place the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` directive in the place you want to render your component. In this case I think your 3rd image.

If I understand you in the correct way you have to place `router-outlet` in a div container between your navbar and your footer to render components by clicking on a `routerLink`. Navbar and Footer are always visible with this approach.

Take a look at the documentation of [router-outlet](https://angular.io/guide/router)

Here is an example for [router-outlet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rweupp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) how it can be done.